# fetch photos of an album in Yii (relation case)

Tags: php, yii, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables , one album and one photo. the photo table has a FK (album_id) which refer to id in album table.

now I want to show photos in CListview but I don't know how. :(

As I see it is uses dataProvider and I don't know how to combine relation with it.

would you help me?
Thank you masters.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Photo', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'album_id=:album_id',
        'params'=>['album_id'=>$album_id]
    )
));
```

Then in view use this dataProvider:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_photo'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should create the relation in you models.
In Album.php add sth like this:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.

    return array(
        'photos'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Photo',array('album_id'=>'id')),
    );
}
```

Similar in Photo.php:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.

    return array(
        'album'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Album',array('id'=>'album_id')),
    );
}
```

Now you can use it in your code:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Photo', array(
    'criteria'=>array(
        'condition'=>'album_id='.$yourAlbumId,
    )
));

$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
...
));
```

If you need to refer to the `Album` in the `CListview` (let's say you have a field called "title" in the Album model), you can refer to it as `$data->album->title` in your items template.

Comment: dataProvider is in Album , the page is album/index not photo

Comment: I don't understand... it does not matter what the page is.. you can add this code in whatever action you like.
and what do you mean by `dataProvider is in Album` ?